# IDA how to remove all uses of a type?

Tags: ida

I'm editing an exe which has a function that is used in multiple places with completely different meanings for the return type (a getter that wasn't inlined). I had assigned it a return type to make it easier to reverse a function, but I'm now having a problem where this type was propagated to ALL calls to the function (so a lot of places have now inferred the wrong type) it's quite tedious fixing it manually as the function has thousands of xrefs.

Is there any way to remove a type and all references to it in the database?